# Convert Python math expression form (Sin and Cos) to Python math expression?

Tags: import, string-manipulation, python

I have a really big symbolic output from Python, and it contains `Sin` and `Cos`. Now I want to solve it using *Mathematica*, but the sin and cos are written like `sin(x) cos(x)`. How can I get them like `Sin[x] Cos[x]` using *Mathematica*?

Comment: While @lowriniak's solution is certainly useful, you might also consider loading the expression into a text editor, and using `ReplaceAll` (ctrl+h).

Answer (score 8):

If this is the only problem then:

```
ToExpression["sin(x) cos(x)", TraditionalForm]
```

> ```
> Cos[x] Sin[x]
> ```

here is a less hacky solution, the assumption is that there are no notmatching `()` escaped in strings or something:

```
FixedPoint[
  StringReplace[
    h : LetterCharacter .. ~~ "(" ~~ Shortest[x__] ~~ ")" /;
      StringCount[x, "("] == StringCount[x, ")"] :> 
    Capitalize[h] <> "[" <> x <> "]"
  ],
  "sin(sin(y))+cos(zxc)"
]
```

> "Sin[Sin[y]]+Cos[zxc]"

Now, you can `ToExpression` if you want.

As george2079 noticed an operator form of `StringReplace` is new in 10.4 so for older versions one may need to use `StringReplace[#, pattern]&` instead of `StringReplace[pattern]`.

`Capitalize` is new in 10.1 so for older versions the replacement would be something like: `StringReplacePart[#, ToUpperCase@StringTake[#, 1], {1, 1}] &`

Comment: Very interesting. What would be a less trivial example? Or does it only cover the simple `(x)` → `[x]`, etc. transformations?

Comment: This is a hack that only works when the syntax is simple. But it is *really* convenient.  I use this all the time to transfer expressions. String patterns can't deal with bracket matching in general. +1

Comment: Seems good. But my first comment wasn't a criticism.

Comment: note the operator form of `StringReplace` is new in 10.4 or so.  Need to do `StringReplace[#, h: .... ]&` for older versions.

Comment: @george2079 thanks, I've added two notes for older versions users.

Answer (score 6):

You could import it as a string then use

```
StringReplace[
  string, 
  {
    "sin("~~Shortest[x__]~~")" :> "Sin["<>x<>"]",
    "cos("~~Shortest[x__]~~")" :> "Cos["<>x<>"]"
  }
]
```

You would then use `ToExpression` to turn it into code input.

Comment: What about `"sin(sin(y))"`?  This is why I prefer the TraditionalForm solution that Kuba showed, even though it is an ugly hack. You could replace all `(` by `[`, but that will replace grouping parens too.  Regular expressions are not capable of dealing with recursive tasks like bracket matching. A proper solution would require a full-blown parser.  The closest ready-made thing we have to that is TraditionalForm parsing.

Comment: Maybe use Anton's parser? https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/FunctionalParsers.m