# How do I convert parentheses of a function into brackets?

Tags: functions, string-manipulation, expression-manipulation

Is there a method to convert the parenthesis of the argument of a function into brackets? What I mean is something like:

$$(x+1)\sin\left(y*\sqrt{y\ln{\left(x^2\right)}}\right)\to(x+1)\sin\left[y*\sqrt{y\ln{\left[x^2\right]}}\right]$$  so that it is evaluatable in mathematica.

To get an idea, I've tried:

```
function = InputString[];
arg = Row[StringDrop[StringDrop[StringCases[function, "(" ~~ __ ~~ ")"], 1], -1]];
temp = ToString[Row[{"(", arg, ")"}]];
temp2 = ToString[Row[{"[", arg, "]"}]];
ToExpression[StringReplace[function, temp -> temp2]]
```

which works if the user inputs simple functions like $\sin(x\cdot e^x)$ but fails for a slightly more complicated function such as $(x+1)\sin(x\cdot e^x)$. I want to generalize this if possible to the example above.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the input? Not only its rendered form? Unless it is TeX, then make that clear.

Comment: At least closely related: [132817](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132817/5478), Shortly `ToExpression["(x+1) sin(y*sqrt(ln(x^2)+ 1))", TraditionalForm]`, though `sqrt` needs a little push.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of [76189](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76189/45431)

Comment: @Kuba Interpreter[“MathExpression”][function] also works, and probably works best because it also converts “ln” to “Log” and is able to handle lower case nested functions. The only issue is that it needs a internet connection.

Comment: @DMH16 yep, is slower and won't work in older versions but may be enough so worth to keep it in mind.

Comment: @DMH16  Self-answering is permitted/encouraged.  Consider adding it as an answer. (Though it didn't work for me -- I think I tested it earlier.  Maybe version dependent?)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what the form of user-input is -- it's typeset TeX output in the question.  If raw TeX is the input form, then this works:

```
Convert`TeX`TeXToExpression[
 "(x+1)\\sin\\left(y*\\sqrt{y\\ln{\\left(x^2\\right)}}\\right)"]
(*  (1 + x) Sin[y Sqrt[y Log[x^2]]]  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a first-order attempt.

We'll check for a head on our round brackets and make sure we have appropriate paren balance. i.e. our pattern will be:

```
pat =
 test : Shortest[head : (WordCharacter ..) ~~ "(" ~~ body__ ~~ ")"] /;
    StringCount[test, "("] == StringCount[test, ")"] :> 
  head <> "[" <> body <> "]"
```

then we'll embed this in a [`FixedPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPoint.html) [`StringReplace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace.html):

```
FixedPoint[
 StringReplace[pat],
 "(x+1) sin(y*sqrt(ln(x^2)+ 1))"
 ]

"(x+1) sin[y*sqrt[ln[x^2]+ 1]]"
```

This is probably still too fragile an approach, however, so it'll probably require work to make robust. We could also add a [`SyntaxQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxQ.html) pre-check in there if we want to make sure everything is good before trying to get the square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [`Boxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boxes) [`InputField`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputField) instead (similar to my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161853/45431) to the linked question [How use TraditionalForm input in InputField?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76189/45431)). For example:

```
DynamicModule[{f=Null},
    {
    TraditionalForm @ InputField[Dynamic[f], Boxes],
    Dynamic[ToExpression[f, TraditionalForm]]
    }
]
```

Here is an animation showing how this works for your example inputs:

[image]